# how to verify all but selected functions from the same module were not called?

Tags: python, mockito

I have a simple module (no classes, just utility functions) where a function `foo()` calls a number of functions from the same module, like this:

```py
def get_config(args):
    ...

    return config_dictionary


def get_objs(args):
    ...

    return list_of_objects


def foo(no_run=False):
    config = get_config(...)

    if no_run:
        return XYZ

    objs = get_objects(config)
    for obj in objs:
        obj.work() 

    ... # number of other functions from the same module called
```

Is it possible to use Python Mockito to verify that `get_config()` was the last function called from my module in `foo()` ? (for certain arguments)

Currently this is verified in this way:

```py
    spy2(mymodule.get_config)
    spy2(mymodule.get_objects)

    assert foo(no_run=True) == XYZ

    verify(mymodule).get_config(...)

    # Assumes that get_objects() is the first function to be called
    # in foo() after the configuration is retrieved.
    verify(mymodule, times=0).get_objects(...)
```

Perhaps something like generating the `spy()` and `verify()` calls dynamically ? Rewrite the module into a class and stub the whole class ?

Basically, I do not like the assumption of the test - the code in `foo()` can be reordered and the test would still pass.

Answer (score 0):

That's not your real code, and then it is often not describing the real problem you have here.  If for example you don't expect a function is called at all, like `get_objects` in your case, then why begin with `spy2` in the first place.  `expect(<module>, times=0).<fn>(...)` reads better in that case, and a subsequent `verify` is not needed.

There is `verifyNoMoreInteractions(<module>)` and `inorder.verify` testing.  But all this is guessing as you don't tell how `XYZ` is computed.  (Basically why `spy2(get_config)` and not a `when` call here.  T.i. why calling the original implementation and not mocking the answer?)